# Please supply working example URLs for each route

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation

It would take a lot of the guess work out of understanding the API if each route's page provided a small handful of working URLs.

This would also serve to provide authoritative examples of the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to have to wait until a 1.0 release, otherwise we're going to run the - quite high risk - of having bad examples laying around for new developers to trip over.

Pre-1.0 as much of the help as can reasonably be, will be built auto-magically.

Comment: are the results examples generated or composed?

Comment: @code poet - Only the descriptions (the first bullet point on Parameters, and the `"description"` key on Returns) are composed by a human.  Everything else is automagically generated.  The degree to which such information is intrinsic in the code itself varies somewhat.

Comment: this is good to know. gives me confidence that my efforts at automating are not likely to be obsoleted. as an aside - your quick efforts at fixing the docs broke my generator. I had to go in and remove special case code and un-fail tests. ;-) good job.

Comment: perhaps a wiki question with a disclaimer would be better than nothing, I can generate a starting set.